# static library c++ with XCode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, static-libraries

I'm trying to create a library of a group of files .cpp and .hpp in xcode.

All files run right in the simulator and in the device without library.

And I have created the library and I have run it in the simulator (architecture x86) and run quite well.

When I tried to run the app with the library in the device I get an error like I would have forgotten any files:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"ssm::partialSortGreater(int, std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > const&, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >&)", referenced from:
```

but It's running in the simulator with the same files, it's mental :S

thanks :)

Update:

BuildSettings:
Library and App
[image: Library]

[image]

Update 2:

Moreover if I Archive the app and I install it with iTunnes, works!!! in the device :S Very weird

Comment: Show us the build-settings of that library and the app that links against it; specifically the architecture specific entries.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check in this instance:

Make sure the library is not set to "Build active architecture only" and make sure that it has ARMv7 set as a valid architecture.

Also, make sure that the main project has your library listed in the Build phases under Target Dependancies and Link Binary with Libraries.

If your library is not building the proper architecture or if your main project is not dependent on it's changes and not currently being linked against the static library your main project will not know that the static library exists.

Comment: I should set Build active architecture only to NO, just in the library, shouldn't I? The rest of the advises are checked, it's weird

Comment: They should both be no, but the static library would be the one that would cause this issue.

Comment: If I set NO in the app then I get error with pods. I think, I should leave YES in the app. Moreover if I Archive the app and I install it with iTunnes, works!!! in the device :S Very weird. Thanks for your answers